# Allocating memory to a passed-in pointer argument

Tags: c, malloc

What is the solution to the following problem:

I have a null pointer which I pass to another function (a central place for doing all allocation and some actions on the allocated memory), which should do the actual allocation on that pointer. This is what I have tried:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void xf(int *p) {
    p = malloc(sizeof (int));
    printf("xf: %p\n", p);
    *p = 123;
}
int *pf() {
    int *p = NULL;
    xf(p);
    printf("pf: %p\n", p);
    return p;
}
int main()
{
    int *a = pf();
    printf("===%p %p===\n", NULL, a);
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    return 0;
}
```

but returned pointer of `pf()` is still the null pointer and not the in `xf` allocated memory address. The above prints something like:

```
xf: 0x56392c0122a0
pf: (nil)
===(nil) (nil)===
Segmentation fault
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You must pass the address of a variable to the called function if the called function is to modify the value so that the calling function can see the change.  Call`xf(&p);` — change the function to `static void xf(int **ppi) { *ppi = malloc(sizeof(int)); **ppi = 123; }` (`static` since it won't be referenced outside this source file — but that's optional).

Comment: If you wrote `int x = 5; f(x);`, and then defined  function `f` as `void f(int x) {x = 6;}` you would not be surprised if the value of `x` in the caller did *not* get changed.  And the same thing is happening here.  Yes, `p` is a pointer, but that doesn't actually make any difference.  When you call `xf`, you cannot change the value of `p` in the caller.

Comment: In addition to the double star pointer approach, another way is: `int *xf(void) { ... return p; }` and invoke with: `int *p = xf();` This is similar to what you already do in `pf` and `main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are changing the pointer so do this

```
void xf(int **p) {
    *p = malloc(sizeof (int));
    printf("xf: %p\n", *p);
    **p = 123;
}
```

and

```
int *p = NULL;
xf(&p);
```